# Trying to get distinct field values from search in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4

I have **Solr 4.10.0** and I have performed indexing for some books. The schema documents are every book's pages, so every document has fields such as, PageID, BookID, PageNum, Content, etc. The fields definition in the schema.xml is like the following:

```
<field name="PageID" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 

   <field name="Content" type="text_ar" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" termVectors="true" />
   <field name="PageNum" type="int" indexed="false" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />
   <field name="Part" type="int" indexed="false" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />

   <field name="BookID" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
   <field name="BookTitle" type="text_ar" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
   <field name="BookInfo" type="text_ar" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
   <field name="BookCat" type="int" indexed="false" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />
```

**The problem**

When I try searching the field `Content` which contains pages text, I will have multiple results from the same `Book`. It is clear that is expected because a certain word may be found in many pages of a book. I tried to make SQL DISTINCT like queries like the following:

1. Using `facet`

   http: //localhost:8080/solr/books/select/?q=Content:WordOfSearch&sort=PageID%20desc&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on&wt=json&facet=on&facet.field=BookID&facet.limit=1&hl=true&hl.q=Content:WordOfSearch

In the previous query I set `facet.field=BookID` to make results have only one result with the same book. However, this solution does not work as expected and it returned results as like `facet` is not used. i.e there is no change with using facet or not.

2. Using `group` I used it with and without the parameter `main` like the following:

   http: //localhost:8080/solr/books/select/?q=Content:WordOfSearch&sort=PageID%20desc&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on&wt=json&group=true&group.field=BookID&group.main=true&hl=true&hl.fl=*&hl.simple.pre=&hl.simple.post=<%2Fspan>

The `group` partially solved the problem. i.e from each book contents -pages- that contains the WordOfSearch it returns one result. However, it corrupts the pagination that I did in my application. In the application I depend on `response: numFound` to maintain the total records. In `group` solution that I have used, it returns `numFound` equals to the number found of a query without group. i.e it returns the number of documents with repeated `BookID` values, so it leads to in empty pages at the last of paging. So, **How could I get the exact number returned documents with `group`?** or any other solution for my problem with repeated `BookID` field values.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to find the list of books that contain pages with the keywords you want. And that you don't care about the specific pages.

In which case, you may want to have separate set of documents representing books (as opposed to just pages) and use [Join Query Parser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-JoinQueryParser) to do the search.

Comment: Although I don't care about the specific pages, I need at least one page from each book the keyword found inside its contents.